# Is greedy "or" group in regex exists?

Tags: python, regex

I have an automatically generated regular expression, which basically is one big "or" group like so:

```
(\bthe\b|\bcat\b|\bin\b|\bhat\.\b|\bhat\b)
```

I've noticed that in case of

```
hat.
```

It would match "hat" only, not "hat." as I want. Is there a way to make it more greedy?

**UPDATE:** forgot about word boundaries, sorry for that.

Comment: You mean besides changing the order of the items?

Comment: @TimCooper, sorry for misleading you, I forgot about word boundaries. Basically I want to allow only a few particular boundaries to be matched ("." in example).

Comment: Factor the word boundaries outside the parens.  ***Don't*** put it next to nonword characters!!!! It doesn’t do what you think it does. Best not use it at all if you don’t understand what `\b` does — and you don’t. Then sort by length, longest first.

Comment: @tchrist, looks like `(\bhat(?:.|\b))` do the trick too

Comment: Andrew, the dot in your `(\bhat(?:.|\b))` needs to be escaped.  But don't bother fixing it; @kindall's  `hat\.?` is much more readable and probably more efficient, too.

Comment: @AlanMoore, yes, the dot should be escaped. It doesn't meant to be readable because it generated and disposed after usage. Also `hat\.?` would match "hat" in `hat,` `hatohshit` and so on.

Comment: Yeah, I should have said `\bhat\b\.` like I did in my comment to @kindall's answer.  Except I factored out the leading `\b` as @tchrist suggested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put `hat\.` before `hat` in the regular expression. The first matching expression in an alternation wins. `hat` matches `hat.` so `hat\.` is never checked.

A better way would to just write that part as `hat\.?` rather than `hat\.|hat`. That makes the period optional so you don't need two terms in the alternation.

After your edit:

There is no word boundary between `.` and, say, a space (both are non-word characters). So `\bhat\.\b` is only going to match in things like `hat.x` where another letter immediately follows the period. This means that in e.g. a sentence, `hat` will be the one that gets matched. I see you found a solution, however.

Comment: You are totally right on this one. I forgot about word boundaries, please review my question.

Comment: That was my thought too: `\b(the\b|cat\b|in\b|hat\b\.?)`